# "Couldn't not convert string to float" error while performing Tfidfvectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

```py
#Model Creation

X = df['v2']
y = df['v1']

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)



pipe_gnb = Pipeline([
    ('vect', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('to_dense', DenseTransformer()), 
    ('gnb', GaussianNB())
])


params_gnb = {
        # 'vect__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
        # 'vect__max_df': [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
        # 'vect__min_df': [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
        # 'vect__max_features': [3000, 4000, 5000, None],
        # 'vect__binary': [True, False],
        'vect__sublinear_tf': [True, False]
}



gs_gnb = GridSearchCV(pipe_gnb, params_gnb, verbose=10, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, scoring='accuracy', error_score='raise')
gs_gnb.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Whenever the fit function of gridsearch obj is called, it gives an error as below:

Error Log->

```py
Fitting 5 folds for each of 2 candidates, totalling 10 fits
---------------------------------------------------------------------------


ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-f57f9dd9e8ed> in <cell line: 46>()
     44 
     45 gs_gnb = GridSearchCV(pipe_gnb, params_gnb, verbose=10, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, scoring='accuracy', error_score='raise')
---> 46 gs_gnb.fit(X_train, y_train)
     47 
     48 # print('Best accuracy: ', gs_gnb.best_score_, end='\n')

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in _return_or_raise(self)
    751         try:
    752             if self.status == TASK_ERROR:
--> 753                 raise self._result
    754             return self._result
    755         finally:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'same i consid wall bunker shit import i never play peac i guess place high enough nt matter'
```

I tried to pre-process the data of the ('v1') column of the given below dataset but the problem still persisted.

Full code->
[Collab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mZTyTIVDB2oz6Fp9QFghc4wy5g7DNQ4J#scrollTo=WDt_AMiOhGLm)

Dataset link->
[Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/sms-spam-collection-dataset)

Comment: You need `TfidfVectorizer`, not `TfidfTransformer`.

Comment: Oh yes thanks! I have been experimenting with different transformers and vectorizers that I didn't paid attention to it. Thanks